# Anatomically(?) correct nanobots

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, technology, science-fiction, physics

With my limited knowledge of chemistry, molecular physics, and quantum computing, I'm struggling to reconcile sci-fi/fantasy trope depictions of (seemingly) impossibly small nanobots with actual physical limitations.

Just how small could individual nanobots plausibly be?

Details, limitations, etc.:

1. Allowances can be made for some specialization between individual units in a "swarm" of nanobots but, as a general rule, *most* individual bots should have *most* of these capabilities:

A. Locomotion,

B. apparatus for communication (preferably wireless/contactless) with other bots in the swarm,

C. a collection of appendages/tools capable of both resource extraction from surrounding environment as well as constructing new nanobots,

D. a power source that either has an extremely long lifespan or can readily extract energy/fuel from the surrounding environment regardless of what environment the bot finds itself in,

E. sensory apparatus for detecting available resources in the surrounding environment,

F. internal hardware/software/equivalent capable of coordinating all of the previous described components(locomotion, sensors, tools, powersupply, etc), as well as working cooperatively with other nanobots, entirely autonomously (without any direct input from humans or any source outside the nanobots themselves, once they start running ... these are not remote controlled, they are self-controlled, "set it and forget it" functions hardwired in to them)

2. Our current manufacturing capabilities can be ignored (assume we'll figure it out eventually), but accepted scientific theory should not be (no Pim particles or handwavium).  In other words, atomic scale or molecular scale should not be used unless it can be explained, with currently accepted scientific theories to back it up, how something that small can incorporate all the previous requirements (locomotion, tools, powersource, communication, sensory equipment, etc)

Comment: VTC as POB: It's nigh impossible to answer this question, let alone in the properly scientific fashion that has become to be expected from a 'anatomically correct' question. From the way you post your question you should've readily already found most of the stuff prople are going to find and be able to contribute yo form a proper answer to this format - lest someone comrs here to whistleblow cutting edge corporate research secrets...

Comment: Tim Blais' take on it... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObvxPSQNMGc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to do better with brutal "hand optimization" but looking at what's been accomplished with 1 million years of parallel development I get the following answers:

### ~300 nm

That is as small as nature has managed to a make something that is for the most part self replicating.  Mycoplasma digest material outside of themselves and then bring in the digested bits to make new selves.  They are on the hairy edge of what is alive, many of them are obligate parasites, not able to make many basic chemicals they need to survive.  They are actually smaller than some mimiviri and bacteriophages.

### 1000 nm

If you want it to move. This is the size of enterobacteria when tend to have all the features you look for in grey goo nanobots, communication (they can swap genes and signaling proteins), motility, reproduction.

*When science finally invents grey goo nanotech and it escapes from the sterile lab and enters the sewer, we will realize we brought a knife to gunfight*

Comment: 1000nm makes it a *microrobot*

Answer (score 2):

Look inside [our cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q3gY.jpg)...

For example [this animation](https://i.imgur.com/TKtA28B.mp4) shows a walking molecule of kinesin, walking along microtubules.

> The inside of a living cell has been compared to a train station at rush hour, with enzymes, chromosomes and other internal components constantly being shuttled along tiny fibrous tracks called microtubules.
>
> Stanford biophysicist Steven Block recently discovered that kinesin heads walk in steps that are exactly 8 nanometers apart. But X-ray crystal analysis of kinesin shows that its two heads are separated by only 5 nanometers of space.
>
> Each 8-nanometer step takes only about 10 milliseconds to complete, says Moerner, noting that the alternating rigid and wobbly states of the two heads could allow kinesin to complete a typical 1,000-nanometer walk in a few seconds before separating from the microtubule.

Inside our cells we have molecular machines transporting around molecules, opening and closing gates, providing structural support and so on.